# FILTERXML get data

Tags: xml, excel, xpath

I am trying to extract a currency exchange rate from [an XML file](http://www.bank.lv/vk/ecb.xml?date=20180803) that looks like this:

```
<CRates xmlns="http://www.bank.lv/vk/LBCurrencyRates.xsd" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bank.lv/vk/LBCurrencyRates.xsd LBCurrencyRates.xsd http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ http://www.dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/dc.xsd" dc:description="The exchange rates are euro reference rates published by the ECB. The reference rates are published daily when TARGET system is open. New rates are typically published between 15:15GMT+2 and 16:00GMT+2." dc:source="http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml">
<Date>20180803</Date>
  <Currencies>
    <Currency>
      <ID>AUD</ID>
      <Rate>1.56890</Rate>
    </Currency>
  </Currencies>
</CRates>
```

I am using this formula to try and get the value of the `Rate` element:

```
=FILTERXML(myxml,"//Currencies/Currency[@ID='AUD']/Rate/.")
```

But I'm unable to get the value I'm looking for.

Comment: This doesn't help you now but Office 2019, will provide access to live data  like exchange rates, stock prices and geographical statistics, that countless users such as yourself currently scrape from the web. ...sooo much simpler.  (a slightly buggy version is available now to those willing to sign up for the ['Office Insider'](https://products.office.com/en-ca/office-insider) program)

Comment: Did you get the xml with `WEBSERVICE`?

Comment: @ashleedawg, yes, I used `WEBSERVICE`

Comment: Question: does anybody know if this function is available in Excel for Mac 2019? Searching the web didn't give me the answer so hopefully SO can help.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is in cell `A2` then you could use:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("<Rate>",A2)+6,FIND("</Rate>",A2)-FIND("<Rate>",A2)-6)
```

***. . .*** or **. . .**

---

### VBA Function: `getTagValue`

Alternatively, you could use this function to extract whatever is between any two strings (or tags) that you specify.

```vb
Public Function getTagValue(xml As String, tagStart As String, _
                    tagStop As String, Optional startPos As Long) As Variant
'returns value from [xml] between [tagStart] & [tagStop], starting at [startPos]

    Dim cStart As Long, cStop As Long
    If startPos = 0 Then startPos = 1 'adjust since [startPos] tag is optional
    cStart=InStr(startPos,xml,tagStart,vbTextCompare)+Len(tagStart)'find tagStart
    cStop=InStr(cStart, xml, tagStop, vbTextCompare)               'find tagStop
    If cStart = 0 Or cStop = 0 Then
        getTagValue = "[n/a]" 'could not find start or end tag
        Exit Function
    End If
    getTagValue = Trim(Mid(xml, cStart, cStop - cStart)) 'get text between tags
    If IsNumeric(getTagValue) Then getTagValue=Val(getTagValue) 'fix if number

End Function
```

### Example Usage:

In a worksheet cell, this:

```vb
=getTagValue(WEBSERVICE("http://www.bank.lv/vk/ecb.xml"),"<rate>","</rate>")
```

...returns a number like `1.5629` (since the value is numeric).

---

If cell `A1` contains the XML, then this:

```vb
=getTagValue(A1,"<ID>","</ID>")
```

...returns a string like `AUD` (since the value isn't numeric).

---

If you want to verify that a tag exists, or count how many times it occurs within a string (like XML), this function returns a count (or `0` if it's not found.)

```vb
Public Function countOccur (searchWithin As String, toFind As String) As String
    'returns the count of occurrences of [toFind] within [searchWithin]
    countOccur = UBound(Split(searchWithin, toFind))
End Function
```

---

## More Information:

- Office Support : [**`FILTERXML` Function**](https://support.office.com/article/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7)
- Office Support : [**`WEBSERVICE` function**](https://support.office.com/article/webservice-function-0546a35a-ecc6-4739-aed7-c0b7ce1562c4)
- Office Docs : [Excel Recalculation: **Volatile and Non-Volatile Functions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/client-developer/excel/excel-recalculation#volatile-and-non-volatile-functions)
- Office Support : [**Text Functions** (Reference)](https://support.office.com/article/text-functions-reference-cccd86ad-547d-4ea9-a065-7bb697c2a56e)

Comment: I suppose it's almost the same as using `FIND` and `MID` in the formula? I thought it would be easyer to parse xml using `FILTERXML` but this workaround is ok too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Excel side of things, but your XPath query is incorrect. The `@` indicates you're looking at an element's attributes, not its content.

Try this instead:

```
//Currency[./ID = 'AUD']/Rate/text()
```

Start with a simple global search for the `Currency` element, then (in the square brackets) do a relative search for the child `ID` element. If it matches, carry on to the `Rate` element and get its text content.

Comment: Thank you for this correction, but sadly still not working in Excel.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test on the Mac version of Excel, because MS didn't bother to write `FILTERXML` for Mac. But you're on the right (x)path; parsing XML files using string manipulation tools is never recommended.

Comment: Perhaps Excel can't read text nodes? I looked at a couple of examples and they just used the element name like `//Currency[./ID = 'AUD']/Rate`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just ran into the same issue and found that the XML Namespace declarations were throwing it off.  After removing those from the XML the FILTERXML function worked as expected.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Not a solution. Removing namespaces makes usage of XML moot.